# Error integrating Pylint on Wing IDE

Tags: python, pylint, wing-ide

After successful installation on Pylint on my Windows OS, I am able to run it on command prompt to check any python file.
But when I integrate PyLint on Wing IDE v 5.0, I am getting below error on checking any python file

```
Error executing PyLint: Command failed with error=None, status=2; stderr:
python: can't open file 'C:\Python27\Scripts\pylint': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something to install or pre-configure. I have set the location of Pylint.bat in PATH variable already.

Comment: I doubt on some environment variable, but not able to figure that out!

Comment: I am still struggling to get this over. Can anyone points me anything regarding.

Comment: What is `command =` set to in your pylintpanel.cfg file?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem here but there should be no quotes around the command name.  So use 'command=C:\Python27\Scripts\pylint' and not 'command="C:\Python27\Scripts\pylint"'.

Comment: Thanks @Wingware : I renamed 'command = C:\Python27\Scripts\pylint.bat' to 'command = C:\Python27\Scripts\pylint' and the problem got fixed.